# Where are Drax's nipples?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, drax-the-destroyer

There was a running joke throughout *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* that Drax has sensitive nipples. This is initially brought up in the opening credits scene when the Guardians are waiting for the interdimensional beast.

> Gamora: Drax, why aren’t you wearing one of Rocket’s aero-rigs?
>
> Drax: It hurts.
>
> Gamora: Hurts?
>
> Drax: *(muttering)* I have sensitive nipples.
>
> <sup>Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2</sup>

It's brought up again when they are fighting Ego and Peter puts an aero-rig onto Drax.

> Quill: Someone needs to be up top when Kraglin arrives. Drax, take Mantis.
>
> *Drax nods. He picks up Mantis. Quill grabs the aero-rig off himself and slaps it on Drax’s back, which automatically wraps around his upper body.*
>
> Drax: Ahhh! My nipples!
>
> <sup>ibid</sup>

However, when taking a closer look at Drax I can't see any nipples on him. In fact even when comparing the character to the actor I am struggling to see Dave's actual nipples underneath all the make up.

[image: Drax] [image: Drax with Groot]
<sub><sub>*Click to enlarge the images.*</sub></sub>

**So, where are Drax's nipples?**

Comment: Drax has mastered the art of keeping his nipples so completely still that they become invisible.

Comment: See the red markings on his skin? *All nipple.* That's why they're so sensitive.

Comment: *This* is the quality content I come to this site to read.

Comment: I can't believe I just spent 10 minutes scouring Batista nipple photos...

Comment: I'll do you one better: *Why* are Drax's nipples?

Comment: Someone just beat me in my area of expertise.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

They are there, but the problem is that Bautista himself does not have large nipples, and they are located low and lateral as can be seen in the below photo:

[image: Dave Bautista]

And, if you look closely in the below photo, you can see the protrusion of his left nipple breaking the line of the curve on his pectoral (left side as well, right side as you look at it):

[image: Drax with the Guardians]

So, he has nipples in the normal place, just hard to see and not very prominent.

Comment: Might just be the angle of the photos I looked at but with the two in the question I still can't see them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - you probably won't in the majority of photos. They are small enough that the makeup covers them almost completely, you'd have to see it at a perfect angle or ***really*** be up close.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot you can see it, I think, in the second photo. [Here?](https://i.imgur.com/NBzQ4Uc.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Much like the line from *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*; maybe not all races have nipples in the same place.  (Obviously the quote from the Star Trek movie was "**not everyone keeps their genitals in the same place**" after the big guy in prison was kicked in the knees.)

Drax is not human, just humanoidesque, so **maybe what he calls nipples, we call  something else.**

(*Not based on any verified source and completely a personal theory.*)

Comment: Oblig: "He's a ballcinian!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NPw3WvpRL8

Comment: I think he more humanoid than *humanoidesque*.  I mean, other than his color, he could basically pass for human. Hell, we even have an actor here on Earth who looks just like Drax.